# routing to a controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a basic question regarding to configuring route in Codeigniter. In my application, I can route through `$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";` perfectly fine. I can use it to route to different controller than welcome controllers as well. However, it does not allow me to route through any other route expressions apart from the default_controller.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['test'] = "welcome";
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

So as I have mentioned already, it takes me to welcome controller if my URL path is localhost/myproject , but it wouldn't let me navigate to the same controller using localhost/myproject/test. I hope you've understood my question.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What it takes you to then?

Comment: $route['test'] = "welcome"; it takes me to 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an index method in your `Welcome` controller to accept your route.

Also Codeigniter will handle many routes automatically. So if you went to `localhost/myproject/test` it will go to the test method of your `default_controller`. So removing that test route and adding the test method would fix this for you.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{ 
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
    }

    public function test()
    {
        echo 'test method';
    }
}
```